# Can't connect to database in new install of EPiServer

Tags: episerver

I have installed a new empty site using EPiServer v8.0.  The site was created using the Visual Studio extension running as Administrator.  When I run the site I get a database connection error:

```
"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Error occurred during LocalDB instance startup: unable to create the SQL Server process.
```

)"

My connection string from web.config is like so:

```
<add name="EPiServerDB" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|EPiServerDB_1293efd2.mdf;Initial Catalog=EPiServerDB_1293efd2;Connection Timeout=60;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I have installed the Alloy site side-by-side and this works OK. The connection string for Alloy is the same as my empty site, with the exception of the database name.

I have lots of these errors in my Event Viewer application log from SQLLocalDB:

```
Windows API call CreateProcessAsUserW returned error code: 740. Windows system error message is: The requested operation requires elevation.
Reported at line: 3705.
```

Comment: Now my Alloy site has stopped working too, with the same error.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you can connect to the database through Management Studio using Windows Authentication (as you have Integrated Security=True in your connection string).

If not, do you have LocalDB installed?

Next, ensure the user for the web app context is able to access the database; if you're running IIS Express this will be the account you used to start Visual Studio.

If you're running full-blown IIS it will be the account for the application pool.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be with LocalDB.  My LocalDB had stopped running so that when I installed the empty EPiServer site the database was not set up correctly.  Strange that the installer didn't return any errors.

It is a recurring problem that I haven't got to the bottom of yet.  LocalDB keeps stopping but I don't know why.